# C# ListView Problem Adding Items

Tags: c#, listview, listviewitem

So, here's my question:  Why won't the code in the first snippet work when the second one works fine.  Also, I have set the view property to details.  I've read all over how to add lvi's to the listview, and it fails every time... except for then I do it manually.

So, this doesn't work...

```
// Iterating through the rows...
for (int x = 0; x < numRows; x++) {
    row = new List<string>();
    // Iterating through the cols...
    for (int y = 0; y < numCols; y++) {
        row.Add(data[y][x]);
    }
    lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(row.ToArray()));
}
```

But this will work:

```
lv.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("foo"));
```

Comment: Can you define "fails"? Also - perhaps check you have the array indexes the right way around...

Comment: In what way does it not work? I just tried it here and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`row.Add(data[y][x])` seems suspicious. Why do you access the data in column-first order but iterate in row-first order? Also, make sure the type of `row` (you didn't tell us this) is actually `List<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

The ListViewItem is looking for a String[] try casting row.ToArray() to a String[].

Comment: Assuming that row is typed as `List<string>` (per the init), then row.ToArray() is already a string[]

Comment: Since row is declared as List<string> ToArray is already coming as string[]; no need to cast.

Comment: @Fredrik - actually, the row declaration isn't shown... we might *assume* it is List<string>...

Comment: I assumed based on this code in the sample: row = new List<string>();

Comment: I just ran the code from above with some quick test data and it worked just fine. What error are you seeing?